# Unique symbol for parallel kernels

Tags: parallelization, scoping

For each kernel, a unique symbol can be generated with `Unique[]`. However, since it's basically defined by the growing `$ModuleNumber`, parallel kernels can only generate unique symbols for themselves, but they are the same across kernels.

MWE:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Unique[i]]
```

So how can I generate unique symbols across all kernels? Of course I can set the `$ModuleNumber` for each kernel during the initialization, but that's way too brute force.

**EDIT**

My use of this unique symbol, for example, is

```
expr1=q.k l.k;
expr2=expr1/.{q.k->Module[{i},q[i]k[i]],l.k->Module[{i},l[i]k[i]]};
expr3=expr2/.k[i_]k[j_]:>delta[i,j];
result=expr3/.q_[i_]l_[j_]delta[i_,j_]:>q.l
```

Comment: Can you give more background to why do you need them? Maybe you don't.

Comment: @Kuba It's for the dummy indices, i.e. $q.k$ is $q^i k^i$ where i is the dummy index. So in the whole expression `i` must be unique and can only appear twice.

Comment: @Turgon please give an example in Mathematica code of an evaluation that requires your dummy indices. The example you gave could obviously be vectorized so I’m not sure it helps much

Comment: @MarcoB I'm not sure if you're familiar with this:i.e. I'd have an expression `q[i$1]k[i$2]kroneckerdelta[i$1,i$2]` and I want to contract those indices such that the result is $q^ik^j\delta^{ij}=q^ik^i$. And the contraction is the last step so before that, I'd have intermediate results with indices I'd like to keep.

Comment: @Turgon Still no functioning code though... Alright, we'll keep guessing! Would [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) be of any help then?

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry...I'm trying to give you an example but I'm not sure if it makes any sense. Plus, as I stated below, it's more like an academic question than what I really need, because I have a workaround for it. `Indexed` is just a fancy way to write my `q[i]` or `k[i]`, it still needs unique indices.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `$KernelID` as a further differentiator?

```
ParallelEvaluate[Unique["i" <> ToString@$KernelID]]

(* Out: {i110, i210, i310, i410} *)
```

Of course you could include `$` in the string name, or any other symbol. Alternatively, you could perhaps do away with Unique, and simply use a combination of a string and `$KernelID`, depending on your usage needs.

---

You could also skip `Unique` altogether and roll your own. I was thinking of something along the lines of the following:

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  Symbol[
    "i" <> ToString[1000 $KernelID + RandomInteger[{1, 999}]]
  ]
]

(* Out: {i1569, i2811, i3512, i4076} *)
```

Comment: If you're unlucky and the `$ModuleNumber` you get is 9, then you have `{i19,i29...}`. At least I've seen `$ModuleNumber` being 700-ish, so in that case you have 1000 unique symbols. Of course most of the time it's more than enough but is there a better solution?

Comment: @turgon how many symbols do you expect to need?

Comment: A few dozens maybe, so your solution is ok for me. I'm only curious if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @Turgon Would the alternative approach in my edit work better then?

Comment: Well how about this `ParallelEvaluate[$ModuleNumber = 10000 $KernelID]`? Random doesn't seem safe when you're trying to make it unique.

Comment: @Turgon Yes that would work as well. I am always loath to change deep built-ins like that, but that's just me being overly cautious. I don't see why this particular change would be dangerous.

Comment: It's true if I change the macro in the middle of something, it might break things. But if it's used to initialize the subkernels, I think it's ok.